# remove the numbers from a string, except if there is a letter before

Tags: r, regex

I have this string:

```
     str <-c ("Street 21, h0use blu3 number 23A", "th3 hosp1tal on 7A Street with 12A")
str <- gsub ("\\ b (?! Street) \\ s [0-9] | [0-9]", "", str, perl = T)
```

this result:

```
"Street, huse blu numberA" "the hosptal onA Street withA"
```

I am trying to eliminate all the numbers, except when they are indicating a street, the result I would like is the following:

```
"Street 21, huse blu number 23A" "th hosptal on 7A Street 12A"
```

Comment: In your expected output `"th hosptal on 7A Street 12A"` the word `with` has been dropped.  Is this intentional, and if so what is the logic behind it?

Comment: sorry, it was exactly a typographical error

Comment: Just a note. `str` is a function in R. You may want to avoid naming an object in this way.

Comment: Thanks, in the case of wanting to omit deleting the numbers when the street word is before, is only what is inside the brackets is modified?
  that is, a result like this: ` "Street 21, huse blu number A"   "the hosptal on A Street with A"`

Comment: @MaxTC Answering that would invalidate the answers already given.  You might want to ask a new question.  Stack Overflow is not a tech blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind to check that a number is preceded by a letter:

```
str<-c("Street 21, h0use blu3 number 23A", "th3 hosp1tal on 7A Street with 12A")
gsub("(?<=[A-Za-z])\\d+", "", str, perl=TRUE)

[1] "Street 21, huse blu number 23A"   "th hosptal on 7A Street with 12A"
```

### Demo

Comment: In the expected outcome, `with` is not included for the second item.

Comment: @jazzurro The OP's description mentions nothing of removing the word `with`.  I propose that it is just a typo.

Comment: That is what I thought too. I guess we need to ask the OP to clarify this point.

Comment: It seems that that was a typo. :)